# c# WCF serialize an xml string

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I've to return an xml string in the response of a WCF method. I've found that the parser sometimes encode the string (e.g  `&lt;test&gt;`) while sometimes it wraps all the string into a CDATA (e.g. `<![CDATA[<test>]]>`).

In particular I've noticed that for strings in which there are a small number of escape characters it uses the first method otherwise the second.

I need to have all the string in the first format, and not in the CDATA. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I've tried to encode the string myself before the response, but then it tries to encode the character "&" and so nothing changes.

Comment: Why do you care how the WCF represents its in transit data? If you are using WCF to WCF communication the other side should not care what the in transit data looks like, it should return the exact same string you passed in.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i think so too, but for some reason the one that has to use the response saied that he is finding some problems with the CDATA section..

Comment: @Viru this is  a simple webmethod that returns a string, that string is xml

Comment: I think that person is consuming service in incorrect manner.....

Comment: I agree with @Viru that person is doing something incorrect on their end and there is nothing you can do to "fix" it because it is a problem with their code, not your code.

Comment: What language/framework/library is the other guy using to consume the Service? I had something similar with a person who was using Lotus Domino to retrieve data from my wcf Service, that is why I ask. I had to change the soap version for him.